# when I click keyboard's back space I get get logged out of the application, adf 12.1.3

Tags: oracle-adf

when I click keyboard's back space I get get logged out of the application, oracle adf 12.1.3, this should not be happening i need to disable this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is browser functionality - the backspace key is the keyboard shortcut for the "back" button:

http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-backspace-chrome-ie-firefox

There are some (not great) ways to disable this in JS, which depend on intercepting the key press event:

[How can I prevent the backspace key from navigating back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495219/how-can-i-prevent-the-backspace-key-from-navigating-back)